# Comparing columns from 2 different files using R

Tags: r, compare

I have 2 files as follows

File 1:

```
Locus   S1  S2  S3
loc1    87  56  77
loc2    34  55  75
loc3    12  09  78
loc4    34  67  89
loc5    78  65  46
```

File 2:

```
Locus   S1  S2  S3
loc3    13  43  34
loc5    43  56  90
loc7    89  56  33
loc1    56  88  00
loc4    66  77  98
loc2    34  44  66
```

I want to compare/match the "Locus" columns from both the files, such that, in the "new_output file", i should have the sequence of the "locus" column from the File1 and values from the respective locus from File2.

So my "new_output file" should look like this,

```
Locus   S1  S2  S3
loc1    56  88  00
loc2    34  44  66
loc3    13  43  34
loc4    66  77  98
loc5    43  56  90
```

I tried something like,

```
file1 <-read.delim(file="file1.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
file2 <-read.delim(file="file2.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
new_output <- file1[file1$Locus %in% file2$Locus,]
write.table(new_output,file="new_output.txt",sep="\t")
```

But thats not really giving me the results the way i want. Can anyone help me with this? And tell me, where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `merge`:

```
merge(file1["Locus"], file2, by = "Locus")

#  Locus S1 S2 S3
#1  loc1 56 88  0
#2  loc2 34 44 66
#3  loc3 13 43 34
#4  loc4 66 77 98
#5  loc5 43 56 90
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Instead of `%in%`, use `match`:

```
new_output <- file2[match(file1$Locus, file2$Locus), ]
```

What you could also do is use `Locus` as row names:

```
file1 <-read.delim(file = "file1.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1)
file2 <-read.delim(file = "file2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1)
new_output <- file2[rownames(file1$Locus), ]
```